# How to remove source from adwords customizer

Tags: google-apps-script, google-ads-api

I played with adwords script published [here](https://developers.google.com/adwords/scripts/docs/solutions/customizer)

After some tests I had several customer sources that I can see using this code:

```
function main() {
  var sources = AdWordsApp.adCustomizerSources().get();
  while (sources.hasNext()) {
  var source = sources.next();
  Logger.log(source.getName());
  }
}
```

But I can't find the way to remove them because I don't need them anymore.

Please, help.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `​AdCustomizerItem.remove()` method to remove a row in your ad customizer source.

From the list of methods given in [**AdWordsApp.​AdCustomizerItem**](https://developers.google.com/adwords/scripts/docs/reference/adwordsapp/adwordsapp_adcustomizeritem),

> `remove()` method removes the ad customizer item.

And as discussed in the documentation:

> AdWordsApp.​AdCustomizerItem represents an ad customizer data item. **Each ad customizer item can be seen as one row in an ad customizer source** in the Business Data section of the Shared Library. Ad customizer items have attribute values, which are values that correspond to the attributes of the item's source. These values can be substituted into an ad with placeholders of the form `{=SourceName.AttributeName}`.

Comment: Removing all items doesn't cause source removement, unfortunately